# Is it possible to change the context of a Scala Worksheet?

Tags: scala, scalatest, scala-ide

Normally running Scala worksheets ends up with the worksheet being evaluated from a blank slate. meaning that anything to want to test or use has to be in scope or initialized already.

Is it possible to run a Scala Worksheet from a different context? e.g. embedded in an application with access to the applications heap / services for prototyping / debugging?

Comment: A few weeks later I discovered the Scalawags podcast crew asking the same question ~4-5 years back. Still think it would be cool if it's possible.